# how openshift ldap auth provider trust self-signed certificate without a rootca signed

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin

I'm trying to config openshift with my internal ldaps server as an IDP.

But the thing is my internal ldaps is self-signed without any root ca signed.

In master-config.yaml, I tried to config the self-signed certificate as ca attribute, but it always complain:

login.go:162] Error authenticating "xifeng" with provider "customer_own_ldap": LDAP Result Code 200 "": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority.

I understand the ca attribute in master-config.yaml might expect a ca-bundle certificate. but my case here its a self-signed cert.

Please advise how I can solve this issue ?

Comment: BTW, during the ssl handshake, the ldap server I'm using expects a client certificate(in this case, openshift as a client). 

So what certificate does openshift send to this ldap server ?

Comment: please can you show your **identityProviders** ldap config? What's in the log of the master server?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm pretty sure the ldap identityProviders config is all Good, 

except the "ca". The "ca" certificate I'm using is not a real CA bundle certificate. 

With openssl x509 -in my_cert.crt -noout -text , it does not contains sth like 'CA: TRUE'. I'm it's not a internal(or trusted) ca root

Comment: BTW, the exception is as below:
TLS handshake error from 10.1.12.139:34120: EOF
Error authenticating "xifeng" with provider "customer_own_ldap": LDAP Result Code 200 "": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority (possibly because of "x509: invalid signature: parent certificate cannot sign this kind of certificate" while trying to verify candidate authority certificate "xfd2")

Comment: please can you show your **identityProviders** ldap config? what's the output of **curl -v --cacert <YOUR-CA-CERT-FILE> ldaps://YOUR-LDAP-SERVER/**

Answer (score 0):

curl -cacert works fine, find below:
 curl -v --cacert xf_ldaps_ca.crt ldaps://bogon:1636
About to connect() to bogon port 1636 (#0)
  Trying 172.16.50.169...
Connected to bogon (172.16.50.169) port 1636 (#0)
Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
  CAfile: xf_ldaps_ca.crt
  CApath: none
NSS: client certificate not found (nickname not specified)
SSL connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Server certificate:
      subject: CN=bogon,O=OpenDJ RSA Self-Signed Certificate
      start date: Dec 23 12:11:19 2016 GMT
      expire date: Dec 18 12:11:19 2036 GMT
      common name: bogon
      issuer: CN=bogon,O=OpenDJ RSA Self-Signed Certificate
LDAP local: ldaps://bogon:1636/
DN: 
        objectClass: top
        objectClass: ds-root-dse

Connection #0 to host bogon left intact

openssl x509 -in xf_ldaps_ca.crt -noout -text
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number: 1440710020 (0x55df7d84)
    Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: O=OpenDJ RSA Self-Signed Certificate, CN=bogon
        Validity
            Not Before: Dec 23 12:11:19 2016 GMT
            Not After : Dec 18 12:11:19 2036 GMT
        Subject: O=OpenDJ RSA Self-Signed Certificate, CN=bogon
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:9e:a4:46:41:d2:9d:32:ae:e3:60:f9:13:ac:40:
                    --------------
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
    Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
         8c:c4:34:2b:af:dd:ec:bc:f0:68:6a:95:53:02:74:d9:9f:5e:
         ----------------

E1223 20:58:37.810976   12227 login.go:162] Error authenticating "xftest" with provider "xf_ldaps_test": LDAP Result Code 200 "": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority (possibly because of "x509: invalid signature: parent certificate cannot sign this kind of certificate" while trying to verify candidate authority certificate "bogon")